# Linq to Entities and Custom properties

Tags: linq-to-entities

I Have an Entity generated from a database table. Then I add a property using a partial class.
This new property is the “description” part of a one to many relation.
The problem is that these sets of entities have like a gazillion and four properties.

I normally use something similar to:

```
db.entity.Select(e => e)
```

But in this case, because the NEW property is not part of the table, it came empty or null.

I know I can do this:

```
db.entity.Select(e => new entityType { field1 = e.field1, field2 = e.field2, etc….})
```

But as a said before… a gazillion properties.

My question is:

**There is some elegant way to just assign the value of the new property and let Linq to fill the rest?**

Something like:

```
db.entity.Select(e => new entityType { *= e.*, newfield = e.relation.desc})
```

Of course, that doesn’t work, but is the idea.

Thanks!

Edgar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach i usually use.

```
   public partial class EntityName
    {

      public string NewProp 
     {

        get {return this.relation.Desc;}
     }

    }
```

Then in the linq query i'll do an include to make sure the related property comes along and i don't get a select n + 1 due to lazy loading.

```
db.entity.Select(e => e).Include(x => x.relation);
```